# Links in PHP help

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

Here is **part** of my my php code:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {

 printf("PDB Code: %s<br>  Protein Name: %s<br> RCSB URL: %s <br> JMOL View: %s <br> Ligand Code: %s<br> Ligand Formula: %s<br> Ligand Name: %s<br> Smile String: %s<br><br> ", $row[0], $row[1], <a href='urlencode($row[2])'>, $row[3], $row[4], $row[5],$row[6],$row[7]);  

}
```

Ive tried everything, so row 2 and 3 are both links, but everytime i apply html link code i get a blank screen. When i remove the code around row 2 and 3 it works fine again.

Iv'e edited the above code so it now contains the problem code.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the code that is causing problems!

Comment: Might need some more info - what is the content of $row[2] and $row[3] and how are you applying the "html link code"?

Comment: $row[2] and $row[3] are url's such as www.website.co.uk its converting in to a link i'm having trouble with

Answer (score 3):

Educated guess: That is most probably because when entering `<a href="....` you break the string by using `"` twice.

Try using only single quotes `'` within the link, or escaping the double quotes like so: `<a href=\"url\">`

Check out the [PHP manual on string syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

You become a blank screen? Turn on immediately the php error reporting during development! You will get error messages that tells you your errors. :-)

Insert on top:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Html code in php must be as a **string** (quoted). Whatch out, php variables in strings are only parsed in doublequotes, or when using concatination.

So do (i prefer):

```
'<a href="' . urlencode($row[2]) . '">'
```

or something like:

```
$row2 = urlencode($row[2]);
"<a href=\"$row2\">"
```